# Zend Framework 3, why can't I bind doctrine entities to forms in the factory?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

Have run into a curious behavior a few times over the years, have always meant to ask about it.

It has to do with a behavior I don't understand around binding objects to forms in Zend Framework.

Consider this factory which builds a form, loads a Doctrine entity from database, and attempts to bind it to the form (so that the values display on render):

```
class TermsConfigFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $form = new TermsConfigForm('terms_config_form', $options);
        $form->setInputFilter($container->get('InputFilterManager')->get(TermsConfigInputFilter::class, $options));
        $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default'), false));

        if (!is_string($options['locale'])) {   
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("An illegal locale variable was received by the terms configuration factory");
        }

        $termsConfig = $container->get(TermsConfigMapper::class)->get($options['locale']);
        if (!$termsConfig) {
            $termsConfig = new TermsConfig($options['locale']);
        }

        // A. If we do just this, the form doesn't print data
        $form->bind($termsConfig);

        return $form;
    }
}
```

The form is well wired through form_elements, and so forth. We then attempt to use it inside a Controller like so:

```
$termsForm = $this->formElementManager->get(TermsConfigForm::class, ['locale' => $this->locale()]);
$viewModel->setVariable('termsForm', $termsForm);
```

Interestingly, we find that the object will not show the bound data in the ViewModel. Now, even more curious, is if we remove the call to "bind" in the factory and do this in the controller instead, the values are properly displayed!!

```
$termsForm = $this->formElementManager->get(TermsConfigForm::class, ['locale' => $this->locale()]);

// B. You have to do this in the controller, here, for it to print data!
$termsForm->bind($termsForm->getObject());
$viewModel->setVariable('termsForm', $termsForm);
```

**Why does it not work within the factory?**

From this vantage point, the call to bind in the controller, is analogous to the call to bind in the Factory.  I'd like to keep this stuff in the factory, but seems I cannot!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the intricacy lies with the FormElementManager that stacks the factory and the init cycle in order.  In other words, init is not called until the factory has completed its work.

Paraphrasing, calling "bind" within a form's factory does not exhibit the same behavior as calling "bind" after the factory returns the form because the Factory calls init (automatically) in between.

Be careful of this 'order of operations' trap.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Factory pattern you'll notice that the job of the factory pattern is to return the desired object only. It has nothing to do with the manipulation of the object. So, with that said all the things you want to do with the desired object should be done in the model object. As the model object can be as fat as it can be. Therefore, I would suggest moving your binding of the desired object out from the factory and move it to the model.

I'll quote something which I saw in a video and Marco Pivetta showed something in a very abstract way and that was something like below:

```
// The below code is my understanding of Marco Pivetta explaining in a youtube video.

use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

class TermsConfigFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
  $form = new TermsConfigForm('terms_config_form', $options);
  $form->setInputFilter($container->get('InputFilterManager')->get(TermsConfigInputFilter::class, $options));
  $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default'), false));

  /*
  This should have been the first line in the method, as it looks like. Because it seems you want locale to be given.
  if (!is_string($options['locale'])) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("An illegal locale variable was received by the terms configuration factory");
   }
  //From here till binding should be moved to a model.
 
  $termsConfig = $container->get(TermsConfigMapper::class)->get($options['locale']);
  if (!$termsConfig) {
    $termsConfig = new TermsConfig($options['locale']);
  }
  
  // A. If we do just this, the form doesn't print data
  $form->bind($termsConfig);
  */
 return $form;
}
```

This is what Marco Pivetta would have done in my opinion according to his video and what I've abstracted.

```
class TermsConfigFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

  if (!is_string($options['locale'])) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("An illegal locale variable was received by the terms configuration factory");
  }
$form = new TermsConfigForm('terms_config_form', $options);
  $form->setInputFilter($container->get('InputFilterManager')->get(TermsConfigInputFilter::class, $options));
  $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default'), false));

  return $form;  
}

// Some model

namespace Mynacespace\Model;

class SomeModel extends /* I don't remember the actual FQCN*/DoctirneRepository
{
    public function dosomething(Form $form ){
      $request = $this->getServiceContainer()->getRequest(); 
      $data = $request->getPost();
      $form->bind($data);
      // do more of your work here.

      // This array returning was not mentioned in Marco video.
      return ['status' => 200, 'message' => 'Success', 'data' => 'form' => $form];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Altamash.  I've no issue with the actual Factory pattern, and I'm absolutely a proponent of implementing very strong validation.  The issue here, however, doesn't lie with the Factory strategy, but with the fact that ->bind() behaves two ways, silently, with very different outcomes.  To reference Ocramius, he also likes to use the term poka-yoke.  This is not poka-yoke at all.

Comment: Hi @Saeven, if it behaves differently then you've just found a bug and you can report it, but with a TTD case. That would make the life of a person like me easier. Also, I apologize for not understanding your point. I gave the answer according to my understanding alone. Thanks!